# Explicación de este ejemplo de for each

Tags: java

mi cuestionamiento es que copie este ejemlo de un tutorial de Pildoras Informáticas y lo que no entiendo es que en la parte en que se define la variable "String c" en el for each, a la hora e imprimir el array suma la variable "c+1" pero ¿Cómo es posible, si ya se estableció que es String?

```
String countries[] = new String[4];

//FOR para recorrer y pedir los paises
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    countries[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese pais " + (i + 1));
}

//FOR para imprimir
System.out.println("paises ingresados por JOptionPane");
for (String c: countries) {
    /*Por que si en cuyo caso c es un objeto de tipo String
    por que se le puede sumar 1
    */
    System.out.println("country " + (c + 1) + ": " + c);

}
```

Comment: No está sumando, está concatenando. Ejemplo: `"hola" + 1` dará como resultado `"hola1"`.

Comment: Me parece que copiaste incompleto o mal el código, también revisé los tutoriales de píldoras informáticas y el código que compartes no habría razón de concatenar al objeto ``c`` el número ``1``,

Answer (score 0):

La variable `c` es un objeto de tipo String  creado para recorrer el arreglo `countries` y al realizar `(c + 1)` lo que estas realizando es una concatenación.
Si bien hay casos en los que un String puedes sumar un número pero esto es luego de parsear, pero el ejercicio que compartes si parseamos `countries` nos dará error porque no es un numeral.
El código tendría que quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
String countries[] = new String[4];

        //FOR para recorrer y pedir los paises
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            countries[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese pais " + (i + 1));
        }

        //FOR para imprimir
        System.out.println("paises ingresados por JOptionPane");
        int c=0;
        for (String s: countries) {
            /*Por que si en cuyo caso c es un objeto de tipo String
            por que se le puede sumar 1
            */
            System.out.println("country " + (c + 1) + ": " + s);
            c++;
        }
```